# TextBlock.Inlines - add horizontal line

Tags: wpf, textblock

Below I am adding log entries divided by a horizontal line

```
 Dim vLogText = vLog.Split("^")
            Dim vRows As Integer = vLogText.Length - 1
            For i As Integer = 0 To vRows
                Dim Subrow As String = vLogText(i)
                LogTB.Inlines.Add(Subrow)
                LogTB.Inlines.Add(New Line With {.X1 = 0, .Y1 = 0, .X2 = 300, .Y2 = 0, .Stroke = New SolidColorBrush(Colors.Gray), .StrokeThickness = 4.0})
            Next
```

This is OK if I want a preset length (say 300 in the above example) - but if it needs to stretch to the entire width of the container how is that accomplished?

Thanks

Added in reply to answer supplied by Anjum

Here is how the grid is added...

```
#Region "Right Grid"

Private Function RightGrid() As Grid
    Try
        Dim MainGrid As New Grid
        Dim vGrid As New Grid
        Dim SV As New ScrollViewer
        With SV
            .Name = "RightGrid_SV"
            .Content = vGrid
            .VerticalScrollBarVisibility = ScrollBarVisibility.Auto
        End With
        RegisterControl(WorkOrder_Grid, SV)
        MainGrid.Children.Add(SV)


        'Add in the status and log

        Dim LogLB As New Label
        With LogLB
            .Name = "WorkOrder_LogLB"
        End With
        RegisterControl(WorkOrder_Grid, LogLB)
        vGrid.Children.Add(LogLB)

        If IsNewRecord = True Then
            'Add some help data
            Dim SP As New StackPanel


            Dim HeaderTB As New TextBlock
            With HeaderTB
                .Text = "ADDING A NEW WORK ORDER" & Environment.NewLine
                .HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center
                .FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold
            End With

            Dim DatesHeaderTB As New TextBlock
            With DatesHeaderTB
                .Text = "Dates"
                .TextDecorations = TextDecorations.Underline
            End With

            Dim DatesContentTB As New TextBlock
            With DatesContentTB
                .Text = "Enter the Work Order date and the date the Work needs to be completed by." & Environment.NewLine
                .TextWrapping = TextWrapping.Wrap
            End With

            Dim UnitHeaderTB As New TextBlock
            With UnitHeaderTB
                .Text = "Unit/Common Area"
                .TextDecorations = TextDecorations.Underline
            End With

            Dim vUnit As String = "If the Work Order relates to a homeowners property, insert the details using the button. "
            vUnit += "If the homeowners have a registered account they will be updated by email each time the Work Order status is changed!" & Environment.NewLine & Environment.NewLine
            vUnit += "If the Work Order relates to a common area (e.g. Recreation grounds, Clubhouse...) just enter a short description of that area." & Environment.NewLine
            Dim UnitContentTB As New TextBlock
            With UnitContentTB
                .Text = vUnit
                .TextWrapping = TextWrapping.Wrap
            End With

            Dim TypeHeaderTB As New TextBlock
            With TypeHeaderTB
                .Text = "Work Type"
                .TextDecorations = TextDecorations.Underline
            End With

            Dim TypeContentTB As New TextBlock
            With TypeContentTB
                .Text = "A short description of the type of work (e.g. Spinklers, Lights not working...)" & Environment.NewLine
                .TextWrapping = TextWrapping.Wrap
            End With

            Dim DetailsHeaderTB As New TextBlock
            With DetailsHeaderTB
                .Text = "Details/Instructions"
                .TextDecorations = TextDecorations.Underline
            End With

            Dim DetailsContentTB As New TextBlock
            With DetailsContentTB
                .Text = "Add any more details or instructions to help the supplier." & Environment.NewLine
                .TextWrapping = TextWrapping.Wrap
            End With

            Dim SupplierHeaderTB As New TextBlock
            With SupplierHeaderTB
                .Text = "Supplier"
                .TextDecorations = TextDecorations.Underline
            End With

            Dim SupplierContentTB As New TextBlock
            With SupplierContentTB
                .Text = "Insert the supplier using the button." & Environment.NewLine & Environment.NewLine & "You can still save the Work Order without entering a supplier, but the Work Order document will not be generated!" & Environment.NewLine
                .TextWrapping = TextWrapping.Wrap
            End With

            Dim EmailHeaderTB As New TextBlock
            With EmailHeaderTB
                .Text = "Supplier Email"
                .TextDecorations = TextDecorations.Underline
            End With

            Dim EmailContentTB As New TextBlock
            With EmailContentTB
                .Text = "The default email address will be loaded when you insert the supplier (this can be overridden) " & Environment.NewLine & Environment.NewLine & "If the email address is blank, or not valid, the Work Order document will not be emailed, but generated as a PDF to print locally and mail!" & Environment.NewLine
                .TextWrapping = TextWrapping.Wrap
            End With

            Dim ImageHeaderTB As New TextBlock
            With ImageHeaderTB
                .Text = "Upload Image"
                .TextDecorations = TextDecorations.Underline
            End With

            Dim ImageContentTB As New TextBlock
            With ImageContentTB
                .Text = "If you have a photograph of the work required, browse to the image. It will be included in the Work Order document." & Environment.NewLine
                .TextWrapping = TextWrapping.Wrap
            End With

            Dim CostHeaderTB As New TextBlock
            With CostHeaderTB
                .Text = "Estimated Cost"
                .TextDecorations = TextDecorations.Underline
            End With

            Dim vCost As String = "If you enter an estimated cost the Work Order will be authorised up to that amount" & Environment.NewLine & Environment.NewLine
            vCost += "If the supplier is unable to carry out the work for this amount or less (or the field is left at zero) the work will not be authorised and they must revert back to the sender with a quote!" & Environment.NewLine & Environment.NewLine
            vCost += "When estimated costs are used a lot it is a good idea to check the supplier invoices do not regularly equal (or a dollar or two less) than the estimated amount!!" & Environment.NewLine

            Dim CostContentTB As New TextBlock
            With CostContentTB
                .Text = vCost
                .TextWrapping = TextWrapping.Wrap
            End With

            Dim SiteHeaderTB As New TextBlock
            With SiteHeaderTB
                .Text = "Smart Manager"
                .TextDecorations = TextDecorations.Underline
                .Foreground = New SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue)
            End With

            Dim SiteContentTB As New TextBlock
            With SiteContentTB
                .Text = "You can also enter Work Orders, whilst on-site, with a Smart Phone or Tablet using Smart Manager!" & Environment.NewLine
                .TextWrapping = TextWrapping.Wrap
                .Foreground = New SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue)
            End With

            With SP.Children
                .Add(HeaderTB)
                .Add(DatesHeaderTB)
                .Add(DatesContentTB)
                .Add(UnitHeaderTB)
                .Add(UnitContentTB)
                .Add(TypeHeaderTB)
                .Add(TypeContentTB)
                .Add(DetailsHeaderTB)
                .Add(DetailsContentTB)
                .Add(SupplierHeaderTB)
                .Add(SupplierContentTB)
                .Add(EmailHeaderTB)
                .Add(EmailContentTB)
                .Add(ImageHeaderTB)
                .Add(ImageContentTB)
                .Add(CostHeaderTB)
                .Add(CostContentTB)
                .Add(SiteHeaderTB)
                .Add(SiteContentTB)
            End With

            LogLB.Content = SP
        End If

        Return MainGrid
    Catch ex As Exception
        EmailError(ex)
        Return Nothing
    End Try
End Function
```

..and that is part of the main grid...

```
Private Function CentreGrid() As Grid
    Try
        Dim vGrid As New Grid
        For i As Integer = 0 To 2
            Dim vCol As New ColumnDefinition
            If i = 1 Then
                vCol.Width = New GridLength(5, GridUnitType.Auto)
            End If
            vGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(vCol)
        Next

        Dim vLeftGrid As Grid = LeftGrid()
        Grid.SetColumn(vLeftGrid, 0)
        vGrid.Children.Add(vLeftGrid)

        Dim vGridSplitter As New GridSplitter
        With vGridSplitter
            .VerticalAlignment = Windows.VerticalAlignment.Stretch
            .HorizontalAlignment = Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Center
            .ResizeBehavior = GridResizeBehavior.PreviousAndNext
            .Background = New SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue)
            .Width = 5
            .Margin = New Thickness(5)
        End With
        Grid.SetColumn(vGridSplitter, 1)
        vGrid.Children.Add(vGridSplitter)

        Dim vRightGrid As Grid = RightGrid()
        Grid.SetColumn(vRightGrid, 2)
        vGrid.Children.Add(vRightGrid)

        Return vGrid
    Catch ex As Exception
        EmailError(ex)
        Return Nothing
    End Try
End Function
```

When the page is opened this is what the horizontal line looks like (the one in blue)

[image: Image one - opened]

..and this is what happens when the GridSplitter is moved to the left (same thing if the window is made larger)

[image: Image two - size adjusted]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best would be to set a `Binding` for the `X2` property and set it to `ActualWidth` of the `TextBlock`.

Below is C# code, you can change it to VB.net :

```
        Line line = new Line() { Stroke = Brushes.Blue};
        Binding binding = new Binding("ActualWidth");
        binding.RelativeSource = new RelativeSource() { Mode=RelativeSourceMode.FindAncestor, AncestorType=typeof(TextBlock) };
        BindingOperations.SetBinding(line, Line.X2Property, binding);

        LogTB.Inlines.Add(line);
```

Comment: That's very close - it sets the width as the page is loaded, but if the TextBlock size is adjusted (window size changes, gridsplitter moved..) it stays fixed at that same width

Comment: @gchq no it doesn't i have checked it.

Comment: Anjum - Thank you for your time! I've just added a couple of screenshots to show before and after, as well as some extra code to show how it's deployed, as that might be a contributing factor.

Comment: Figured it out - change the ancestor type to Grid and now it works perfectly - thank you for getting me on the right track

Answer (score 2):

I would not use code-behind for something like this. Absolutely painful. You'll find `WPF` much easier to work with if you confine the majority of UI development to an XAML front-end. Try something like this

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication3.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication3"
        xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.Resources>
            <DataTemplate x:Key="MyTemplate">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" />
                    <Line X1="0" X2="{Binding ActualWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Stroke="Black" />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Grid.Resources>
        <ItemsControl ItemTemplate="{StaticResource MyTemplate}">
            <ItemsControl.Items>
                <sys:String>One</sys:String>
                <sys:String>Two</sys:String>
                <sys:String>Three</sys:String>
            </ItemsControl.Items>
        </ItemsControl>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Hi Jace - thanks for the reply. The project is way too large to manage XAML (can be 20k lines to a page) and there are a number of DB fed dynamic settings so everything is written in code behind apart from a skeleton for the Main Window. With code behind it's easier to locate and make changes

Comment: You owe it to yourself to take a crash-course in MVVM, as well as MVC. Whenever I hear someone say "everything is written in code-behind", they've usually done things the hard way.

Comment: Jace - A appreciate what you say, and it probably is a lot harder - but with so much loaded dynamically I have little choice. In the example that is part of the question different grids are loaded onto the page according to user selection and then other items are loading dynamically based on back-end data

Comment: I have marked this up, but not as the answer, as basically it was the correct, but not in the format I was looking for

Comment: You might want to submit an example. Honestly, from the way you describe the situation, this sounds like the type of project XAML was made for.